# how to import angular2 feature modules from external domains

Tags: angular, web, lazy-loading, single-page-application, systemjs

I am working on an angular application which acts as a container application and hosts and lazy loads multiple other angular2 applications as its feature modules. These applications are deployed as microservices and can be accessed via their own urls.

The problem I have is that how do I determine assets urls for these sub applications when they are integrated in the container application. I cannot have base url set for sub apps because their index page won't be loaded inside container app.

Comment: Hi, how do you perform the lazyloading of the other applications?

Comment: The other applications are built as feature modules and can be lazily loaded..